# How do you feel about this?

Tags: rebus

$$\frac{(023456789)\space\text{SKOOL}}{\text{THE ANSWER}} + \text{CONFUSION}$$

Comment: Inspired by the previous question?

Comment: Only mildly, yes.

Comment: I cannot find the word "skool" in dictionary. What does it mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possibly (though it doesn't feel quite right):

> No one looks back on the answer with some confusion.

Comment: Maybe "over" instead of "on"? And without the "some"

Comment: @DennisMeng - yeah, I originally had "over", but felt the sentence sound better with "on" (not that it makes a huge difference either way). As for "some", I figured that "+" => "sum" => "some" warranted the inclusion, otherwise the rebus could have just left the "+" out altogether.

Comment: *shrug*. Grammatically I always used "over", and I assumed that the "+" accounted for the "with", but either way, I agree with the general idea of the solution

Comment: Dennis is right; the + was just meaning "with".